# Sharp focus photography with APS-C

Tags: post-processing, focus, sharpness, sharpening, focus-distance

So, it happens that I am really passionate about the sharp focus photography, where some points on the picture looks sharper than the usual, just like the example I've attached.

My question is: how can I achieve this type of result, with my APS-C camera? (A Canon 60D)?

My main questions are:
- What kind of body (Full Frame or not) should I need to have to get these results?
- What kind of lens should I use? L lenses from Canon?
- What are the best settings to achieve this? (aperture, Iso, exposure, etc?)
- What kind of adjustments can I do to my camera in order to get the closest results to this one as possible?
- What kind of post processing (mainly on Lightroom) should I do to get this results?

Any help would be deeply appreciated, thank you very much.

[image: Photo from @wojtekstark]

Comment: You're pretty much asking for a complete set of lessons on photography and post processing.

Comment: Not exactly a "complete set of lessons", but I'd like to get to know more about the subject, as it would help me a lot in guiding me during my future researches.

Comment: That's far too broad for this site, which uses a simple Q&A format.

Comment: Ok, got it. Any direction where I could get more info about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp)

Comment: @paulovlobato You can get more info on this site. You don't need to go off to somewhere else. But, this happens to be particularly broad; you're not likely to get results like this just from dialing in certain settings.

Comment: @paulovlobato What is the original source for this image? Who is the photographer?

Comment: @mattdm My bad I thought the author was visible at the body of my question. The photography is from a profile called "@wojtekstark", you can find him on Instagram.But the print screen is from a page called "@depths_of_world". They've shared his photo.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/p/Bfc4EwkgGBR/?taken-by=wojtekstark

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely nothing about this photo that requires a camera more advanced than your Canon 60D and a $100 lens.

The basics are:

1. Good lighting — a whole topic to itself
2. Stop down the aperture a bit, which you can because lighting is good
3. Nail focus, which is less critical because you stopped down
4. In post-processing, crank sharpening and "clarity" up beyond natural-seeming levels until you get the look you like.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm pretty sure the example was shot on medium format film.

Comment: Please see [How can these photos by Martin Schoeller have such a high quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9421/15871) and Stan's (user2719) answer to [How can a high resolution camera matter when the output is low resolution?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/31283/15871) for more.

Comment: Make that LF, not MF.

Comment: Again, the 2nd example in [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82713/15871) shows fairly clear evidence that a view camera (or at the very least a tilt lens) was used to tilt the plane fo focus.

Comment: Maybe; it's hard to tell here with the low-res instagram screenshot. I agree that the other question has examples taken with larger-format (although I don't think necessarily view cameras).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, bigger is better! The image sensors of the various digital camera types vary in size. The so called full frame image sensor is a copycat of the image size yield of the esteemed 35mm film camera. These image sensors measure 24mm height by 36mm length. The full frame size is often called FX in the jargon of the industry. Other camera types sport a smaller image sensor fashioned after a film format known as Advanced Photo System. These sensors measure 16mm height by 24mm length. The industry jargon for this smaller senor size is APS-C (the C is for classic format) often this format is called compact digital or DX.

The size of the image sensor somewhat relates to the most important factor which is pixel count. As a rule of thumb, the higher the pixel count, the higher the resolution. However, picture quality is also affected by the actual size of the photosite (pixel).  Larger photosite likely deliver a higher resolution picture.

That being said, as to sharpness and resolution, much depends on how you view your pictures. The typical computer monitor and or TV display a lowered pixel count. Picture taken with camera with a super hight pixel count and then viewed on a typical computer monitor, suffer in this regard. This is true because most likely the software of the viewing system will discard a high percentage of the pixel count.

While pixel count and sensor size is important, it is likely not as important as you might think. Time marches on and todays compact cameras are quite satisfactory for most imaging tasks.